# How should I call splitted functions? centralize them? or call it one next to one?

Tags: coding-style, functional-programming, readability

According to [Is it OK to split long functions and methods into smaller ones even though they won't be called by anything else?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195989/is-it-ok-to-split-long-functions-and-methods-into-smaller-ones-even-though-they), I should split long functions into smaller functions even if they are used once only, but my question is , how should I call the extracted functions?

Style 1: centralize them

```
callFunctions(){
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
}
```

Style 2: call it one by one:

```
function1(){
  .
  .
  .
  function2();
}

function2(){
  .
  .
  .
  function3();
}
```

Which style should I use?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: normally style 1 i'd say. style 2 looks like it might related to but not quite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the centralized approach myself, rather than the chained approach.

With the chained approach, you're not gaining anything except a little bit of readability in that you now have a few small functions instead of one large one (and you're not really gaining any readability into the steps taken to complete the larger action, because you then have to read through each of the chained functions to see what's happening across the board).

With the centralized approach, you gain two distinct advantages:

1. You can now very easily see, from the main function, what steps are required to complete the whole task
2. Each of the smaller functions can now be more easily isolated in that they are less likely to have external factors governing how they run (e.g., you can more easily re-use some of these steps later, if need be)

Comment: Also, there will be cases where calling a function is dependent on the success or failure of the previous one. I personally find it easier to follow and debug that in the centralized model.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to jleach's answer, the reason the "centralized" approach is preferable is that code in functions should usually be at the same level of abstraction (see: Single Level of Abstraction).

In your example, `callFunctions()` is on a more abstract level, composing the necessary computations into finer steps `functionN()`. Then these "split" functions go into more detail and are less abstract.

Since `functionN()` is on this finer level of detail, calling other `functionN()`s, which is a function call on the higher level of abstraction, within `functionN()` would break the rule of "same level of abstraction within a function".