# Should I extract method to reduce duplication if the resulting method's functionality will vary based on type of collection given to it?

Tags: object-oriented-design, methods, dry

I am designing a **`treeNode`** class. While implementing the **`getPathToParentNode()`** and **`getPathFromParentNode()`** methods, I noticed that their functionality is essentially the same - they just operate on different data structures.

**`getPathToParentNode()`** recursively adds all parent nodes into a *queue*, and then creates the path using the queue iterator.

**`getPathFromParentNode()`** recursively adds all parent nodes into a *stack*, and then creates the path using the stack iterator.

To adhere to the DRY principle, I was thinking of extracting the duplicate code (recursively adding parents to a *collection*, and using the *collection* iterator to generate the path) into a separate function, and just passing it a queue from the first function and a stack from the second function.

```
// takes in a queue or a stack
// returns path to root node or path from root node respectively
List<ITreeNode<T>> getPath(Collection<ITreeNode<T>> pathCollection) {

    pathCollection.add(this);

    ITreeNode<T> parent = this.getParent();
    pathCollection.add(parent);

    while (parent.getParent() != null) {
        pathCollection.add(parent.getParent());
    }

    return new ArrayList<ITreeNode<T>>(pathCollection);
}
```

However, the resulting helper function doesn't feel right. I don't think it performs something independent/worthwhile enough to justify its existence. Furthermore, its *objective* changes based on the type of collection passed into it, and perhaps as a consequence of that, it is difficult to name.

Is such a method considered "good" in light of the principles of object-orientated design? What would be a better approach?

**Edit:**

Similar question regarding method extraction in general (but the answers do not address my specific case):
[Should I extract specific functionality into a function and why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/166884/180202)

Comment: I think this one might come down to too much of an opinion based discussion. Personally I would probably have two separate functions and skip over DRY in this context in favour of clarity, but I wouldn't be at all put out if someone presented me with your code to work with either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I extract specific functionality into a function and why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166884/should-i-extract-specific-functionality-into-a-function-and-why)

Comment: That is about method extraction in general - I was asking about my specific case.

Answer (score 2):

You could have both implemented with a DQueue and just use an end selector to determine whether it is used FIFO or FILO, (First In First Out = Queue, First In Last Out = Stack). Then the two functions would become a single one with a direction specifier.  Much simpler and no need for template specifiers.

Comment: What would be a good format for the direction specifier? Is an enum appropriate here?

Comment: You could just use a bool called something like upwards or a enum of upwards, downwards would be clearer.

Comment: If you go with the enum, make the name like queue/stack or fifo/filo.

Comment: @RobertBaron Or "Direction.FromParent"/"Direction.ToParent"

Comment: Decedents/Ancestors there are lots of possibilities. TopDown/BottomUp will probably raise a smile from future maintainers.