# Is it unnecessary to have a method that merely loops through an array and calls another method with each item?

Tags: coding-style, array

For example, if there's multiple lines to be drawn, I could do

```
function drawLines(lines) {
    lines.forEach(function (line) {
        drawLine(line);
    });
}
function drawLine(line) {
    //...
}
```

and then in the "main" section of the code I would merely have to call `drawLines(lines)` rather than writing a `forEach` there.

This does prevent the need for multiple `forEach`'s to be written if there's more than one section of code that needs to render some lines. I'd only need to call `drawLines(lines)` in any such place. But at the same time, it just feels like a bit of a silly thing to do.

(The lines thing is just an example... I'm just talking about the general concept of "do something with each item in an array").

Comment: It clearly is unnecessary, as you could put all the code in one method. But that would result in a difficult to read mess. As such it's a bit unclear what you are asking. Do you really want to know whether it's necessary, or whether it's good practice, to organise code into small, easy-to-read parts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I extract specific functionality into a function and why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166884/should-i-extract-specific-functionality-into-a-function-and-why)

Comment: Depending on language mechanics, you could always split the difference and do `lines.forEach(drawLine);`

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good question, and somewhat subtle. I assume your style is object oriented? If you are using functional or imperative, the answer would be different.

An array have no further semantics than being a collection of items, so clients should treat it as that, i.e. use collection operations like `forEach`.

But the question is if the lines should be passed around as an array in the first place. Since you are tempted to write a method `drawLines()` which treat the array of lines as a whole, it indicates you should consider encapsulating the array of lines in a distinct `Figure` object. You would have a `Figure.draw()` method, which internally would call `drawLine()` (or preferably `line.draw()`) on each line.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with you about using a `Figure` class but only if the behavior of drawing several lines is somehow different or could *potentially* be different than drawing them one at a time.  Of course it could happen to be the same initially, but it makes for more elastic code.  If drawLines only calls drawLine for each line with no intention of extending behavior, it should not be done in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Neil: I disagree - I think the decision should be based on whether the client *needs to know* if drawLines just calls draw on each individual line or does something more. If the client don't need to know, it should be encapsulate.

Comment: The OP's question is implicitly framed in terms of DRY, but separation of concerns, namely interface vs. implementation may have more bearing here.  A look at the larger context (not shown by the OP) might suggest an improvement in the abstraction(s) being offered.

Comment: @JacquesB I wouldn't mind if the client/caller would only need drawLines, but if you offer the client/caller a choice between calling `drawLine` repeatedly and one call to `drawLines`, the natural conclusion is that there must be a difference, even if only at the level of optimization.  If there *is* no difference and no intentions of having a difference in the near future, it is only misleading and verbose in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If it's more than a line of two lines I would do it that way. Drawing a single line is easy but drawing in general can involve a bunch of steps and can be confusing for the next person that comes along, for that reason I would generally put drawing logic in a method like this. It kind of has to do with theme and making into bite sized chunks. Drawing uses different concepts to loops and data structures and separating drawing means the person looking at it only needs to think about drawing and then they are looking at the loop they only need to understand that drawing gets done.